# Intermittent problems when accessing and editing documents

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am experiencing on shared drives. The problem is failure or significant delay when accessing or updating documents ( Word Autosave) and when trying to view folder contents. No significant event logs have been found either the share (server 2008) or W7 client the are on wireless LAN an AVG Business is the AV.

Has anyone had this issue?
Would anyone like to comment on likely cause?

Comment: Have you tested for bandwidth/capacity problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many factors that can be doing this. You don't mention how many people are using the shared server, what the load is on the drives, if the disk subsystem or network on the server (or infrastructure) is creaking under load, etc.

Is it possible the AV is causing problems? Yes, it's possible, if it's monitoring or fooling with file or network access which most AV today do. You can test it by turning it off on the server and client and see if that changes things.

MS Office really really *really* doesn't like it if your network access isn't 100% stable. We've had numerous instances over the years of a document "locking" where it wouldn't save or update once a network glitch caused the application to lose contact with a remote document; the only way around it was to open a new document and cut and paste content to the new version then save as a new document.

You said it's a wireless network; have you checked for interference of the radio channels? Other wireless systems, appliances creating noise, etc.? Are you sure you're just not overloading equipment or have flaky hardware?

In the end you have a lot of potential issues to check.

Server-disk performance, memory full/disk thrashing, network I/O overloaded, fragmentation slowing access?

Network- interference on channels, overloaded connections, flaky hardware?

Client - A/V blocking or interfering with access, client network access issues, crappy driver on network card, bad or flaky network card?

General patterns - does this seem to cluster around a particular time of day (so it could be load-specific)? Is the server used for sharing profiles, or other purposes? Does this seem to happen to a particular user or set of users (bad client machine or flaky hardware to a particular area?)

You'd have to just create a big old list and start hacking away at it to eliminate possibilities. Performance monitor on the servers, ping tests, hardware monitoring on the router/switch/WAP's, disable AV on the client for awhile, etc. It's just too broad for a quick answer of what could be wrong.

Comment: Cheers Bart will go through its a good list for me to start with, Let you know the outcome.